# Flutter PageView.builder Issue: Images Beyond Initial View Not Rendering Correctly During Horizontal Scroll

Tags: flutter, dart, state-management, flutter-pageview, image-rendering

In this code i am encountering an issue within a **PageView.builder** widget in a Flutter app. The PageView.builder is meant to display multiple product images in a horizontal scrollable manner. However, the images beyond the initial view (images indexed after the first few) are not displaying as expected when swiping through the images. Instead, the screen flickers or doesn't update to show the subsequent images beyond the first few.

Despite confirming the presence of the images through debugging (the correct imageUrl values are retrieved), the PageView.builder seems to have trouble rendering these images beyond the initial ones visible on load. We've ensured that the state is updated correctly by using productNotifier.activePage in onPageChanged and triggering a rebuild with setState(). Despite this, the subsequent images fail to display properly within the PageView.builder.

The goal is to have a smooth horizontal scroll functionality within the PageView.builder, allowing users to view and navigate through all product images seamlessly. We're seeking insights into why the subsequent images are not rendering or updating properly when swiping through the images and how to resolve this issue effectively.

**here is the ProductPage code:** // i have reduce the complexity in the code because it was too long

```
class ProductPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const ProductPage({super.key, required this.id, required this.category});

  final String id;
  final String category;

  @override
  State<ProductPage> createState() => _ProductPageState();
}

class _ProductPageState extends State<ProductPage> {
  final PageController pageController = PageController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var favouritesNotifier = Provider.of<FavoritesNotifier>(context);
    favouritesNotifier.getFavorites();

    var productNotifier = Provider.of<ProductNotifier>(context);
    productNotifier.getProducts(widget.category, widget.id);
    return Scaffold(
      body: FutureBuilder<Products>(
        future: productNotifier.products,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return const CircularProgressIndicator();
          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Text("Error ${snapshot.error}");
          } else {
            final products = snapshot.data;
            return Consumer<ProductNotifier>(
              builder: (context, productNotifier, child) {
                return CustomScrollView(
                  slivers: [
                    SliverAppBar(
                      automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
                      leadingWidth: 0,
                      title: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),
                        child: Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                          children: [
                            GestureDetector(
                              onTap: () {
                                Navigator.pop(context);
                                // productNotifier.productSizes.clear();
                              },
                              child: const Icon(Ionicons.close),
                            ),
                            GestureDetector(
                              onTap: null,
                              child: const Icon(Ionicons.ellipsis_horizontal),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      pinned: true,
                      snap: false,
                      floating: true,
                      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                      expandedHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                      flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
                        background: Stack(
                          children: [
                            SizedBox(
                              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.5,
                              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                              child: PageView.builder(
                                itemCount: products!.imageUrl.length,
                                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                                controller: pageController,
                                onPageChanged: (page) {
                                  productNotifier.activePage = page;
                                  setState(() {});
                                },
                                itemBuilder: (context, int index) {
                                  return Stack(
                                    children: [
                                      Container(
                                        height:
                                            MediaQuery.of(context).size.height *
                                                0.39,
                                        width:
                                            MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                                        color: Colors.grey.shade300,
                                        child: CachedNetworkImage(
                                          imageUrl: products.imageUrl[index],
                                          fit: BoxFit.contain,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      Positioned(
                                          top: MediaQuery.of(context)
                                                  .size
                                                  .height *
                                              0.06,
                                          right: 15,
                                          child: Consumer<FavoritesNotifier>(
                                            builder: (context,
                                                favoritesNotifier, child) {
                                              return GestureDetector(
                                                onTap: () {
                                                  if (favoritesNotifier.ids
                                                      .contains(widget.id)) {
                                                    Navigator.push(
                                                      context,
                                                      MaterialPageRoute(
                                                        builder: (context) =>
                                                            const Favorites(),
                                                      ),
                                                    );
                                                  } else {
                                                    favouritesNotifier
                                                        .createFav({
                                                      "id": products.id,
                                                      "name": products.name,
                                                      "category":
                                                          products.category,
                                                      "price": products.price,
                                                      "imageUrl":
                                                          products.imageUrl[0],
                                                    });
                                                  }
                                                  setState(() {});
                                                },
                                                child: favoritesNotifier.ids
                                                        .contains(products.id)
                                                    ? const Icon(Ionicons.heart)
                                                    : const Icon(
                                                        Ionicons.heart_outline),
                                              );
                                            },
                                          )),
                                      Positioned(
                                        bottom: 0,
                                        right: 0,
                                        left: 0,
                                        height:
                                            MediaQuery.of(context).size.height *
                                                0.3,
                                        child: Row(
                                          mainAxisAlignment:
                                              MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                          children: List<Widget>.generate(
                                            products.imageUrl.length,
                                            (index) => Padding(
                                              padding:
                                                  const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                                      horizontal: 4),
                                              child: CircleAvatar(
                                                radius: 5,
                                                backgroundColor: productNotifier
                                                            .activePage !=
                                                        index
                                                    ? Colors.grey
                                                    : Colors.black,
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  );
                                },
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                );
              },
            );
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**here is the ProductNotifier class code:**

```
class ProductNotifier extends ChangeNotifier {
  int _activePage = 0;
  List<dynamic> _productSizes = [];
  List<String> _sizes = [];
  final _cartBox = Hive.box('cart_box');

  int get activePage => _activePage;

  set activePage(int newIndex) {
    _activePage = newIndex;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  late Future<List<Products>> male;
  late Future<List<Products>> female;
  late Future<List<Products>> vintageAndRetroStyle;
  late Future<Products> products;

  void getMale() {
    male = Helper().getMaleProducts();
  }

  void getFemale() {
    female = Helper().getFemaleProducts();
  }

  void getVintageAndRetroStyle() {
    vintageAndRetroStyle = Helper().getVintageAndRetroProducts();
  }

  List<dynamic> get productSizes => _productSizes;

  set productSizes(List<dynamic> newSizes) {
    _productSizes = newSizes;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void toggleCheck(int index) {
    for (int i = 0; i < _productSizes.length; i++) {
      if (i == index) {
        _productSizes[i]['isSelected'] = !_productSizes[i]['isSelected'];
      }
    }
    notifyListeners();
  }

  Future<void> createCart(Map<String, dynamic> newCart) async {
    await _cartBox.add(newCart);
  }

  List<String> get sizes => _sizes;

  set sizes(List<String> newSizes) {
    _sizes = newSizes;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void getProducts(String category, String id) {
    if (category == "Men's Fashion") {
      products = Helper().getMaleProductsById(id);
    } else if (category == "Women's Fashion") {
      products = Helper().getFemaleProductsById(id);
    } else {
      products = Helper().getVintageAndRetroProductsById(id);
    }
  }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VyfBN.gif)

**What I tried:**

Implemented a PageView.builder widget to display product images horizontally.
Confirmed correct retrieval of image URLs and data through debugging.
Used productNotifier.activePage in onPageChanged to trigger a rebuild with setState().
Ensured that the state updates properly upon swiping through images.
Expected Outcome:

I expected the PageView.builder to smoothly render and display all product images, allowing seamless horizontal navigation through each image.

**Actual Result:**

The initial set of images displays correctly. However, when swiping through to view subsequent images beyond the initially visible ones, the screen either flickers or fails to update/render these images properly within the PageView.builder. Despite confirming the presence of the images (correct image URLs retrieved), the subsequent images are not displaying as expected during the horizontal scroll.